# M/Monit how to see current disk space?

Tags: disk-space-utilization, monit, system-monitoring

In the admin interface of M/Monit under Reports -> Analytics I can chose to show **Space %**.

1. How can I make the Monit clients submit this info?
2. Is there a way to display Disk Space percentage on the Status page besides **%Cpu** and **%Mem**?

*I have found that I can set alerts if disk space is running out (will do that, but would like to have an overview as well).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see this information on the `Reports -> Analytics` page.

[image]

Your Monit config needs to have disk checks for the filesystems you require:

```
check device root with path /
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

check device var with path /var
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

check device usr with path /usr
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

check device tmp with path /tmp
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert
```

There's no way to add disk space to the overview graph. It wouldn't make sense from a design or UI perspective.

[image]

Comment: Thx! Quick answer :-) Got it to work. A bit confusing that I have to set an alert to monitor a specific info. Why doesn't it make sense in the UI? It would fit easily in just another column.